# Android - Changing Fragments within an Activity

Tags: android, fragment

I am creating an Android app that uses a main activity, and several fragments. The main activity is the min "control" for everything, and each fragment displays a different screen with different information. Here is some of the code for my main activity:

```
public class MainMenu extends FragmentActivity implements FirstMenu.FragmentListener, Checklist.FragmentListener,
    Tool.FragmentListener{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

    FirstMenu firstMenu = new FirstMenu();

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container,
            firstMenu).commit();
}

public void changeScreen() {

    Checklist checklist = new Checklist();

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, checklist);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();

}

public void changeScreenTwo() {

    ChemicalCheckList chemChecklist = new ChemicalCheckList();

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, chemChecklist);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();

}
```

And here is the code for my first fragment which displays the menu:

```
public class FirstMenu extends Fragment {
    FragmentListener fragmentChanger;

    public interface FragmentListener {
        public void changeScreen();
        public void changeScreenFour();
        public void changeScreenFive();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            fragmentChanger = (FragmentListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException();
        }
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        container.removeAllViews();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, container, false);

        Button checkListButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.checklistButton);
        Button toolButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.toolButton);
        Button timeFuseButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.timeFuseCalculator);
        Button blastFragButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.blastFragButton);
        Button demoButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.demoButton);



        checkListButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        buttonClicked(v);
                    }
                }
        );

        toolButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        toolButtonClicked(v);
                    }
                }
        );

        demoButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        demoButtonClicked(v);
                    }
                }
        );




       blastFragButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), BlastFrag.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        timeFuseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TimeFuse.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return view;

    }

    public void buttonClicked( View v ) {
        fragmentChanger.changeScreen();
    }
    public void toolButtonClicked( View v ) {
        fragmentChanger.changeScreenFour();
    }
    public void demoButtonClicked( View v ) {
        fragmentChanger.changeScreenFive();
    }
}
```

And this is the code for the second fragment, which is displayed to the screen by using the method changeScreen();

```
public class Checklist extends Fragment{
    FragmentListener fragmentAlternator;

    public interface FragmentListener {
        public void changeScreenTwo();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            fragmentAlternator = (FragmentListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException();
        }
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        container.removeAllViews();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.checklists, container, false);

        Button chemButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.chemButton);


        chemButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        buttonClicked(v);
                    }
                }
        );

        return view;
    }
    public void buttonClicked( View v ) {
        fragmentAlternator.changeScreenTwo();
    }
}
```

I have many more fragments that are displayed to the screen using more methods, such as: changeScreenTwo(), changeScreenThree(), changeScreenFour(), etc. The code for the methods is all pretty much exactly the same. The only difference is that it is creating different objects from different classes. I'm wondering if the current way I'm doing it is okay, or if there is a way I can make all these "changeScreen" methods into one method, and simply pass in each type of class as a parameter. I've looked all over and can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for with this particular situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass in a fragment index and use it to choose the fragment type.

```
public void changeScreen(int position) {
    switch(position){
        case 0:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Checklist())
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
            break;
        case 1:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new ChemicalCheckList())
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I implemented this solution and it seems to be working well. I was looking for a way to clean up the code a little bit, it didn't feel right doing all that copy and paste and making multiple functions that did the same thing.